# Is charging a laptop when shut down better for it's life span?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging, lifespan

If it helps my laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 510. It's pretty new, and I want it to last for a long time. The laptop has an internal battery. Is that expensive to be replaced?
If I charge it when is on or asleep, it sometimes heats up and I heard that that is bad for the battery. When I charge it shut down, there is no heat. Advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

charging the laptop while it is shutdown it's better for the battery life, and also the laptop won't heat up as you've noticed ,but you can also keep it plugged in while in use but as soon as the battery reaches 100% you should unplug it ,if you want to avoid the heat up ,hope this answer will help.